# MySQL server gone away when doing multiprocessing - python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to do something with data in MySQL DB using multiprocessing. Every-time I run the following code, it says `MySQL server has gone away`. If I run this without multiprocessing, it works fine.

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(**MYSQL_SETTINGS)

    def books_query(self, offset):
        """Return books_query."""
        return 'SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY id limit 1000 offset ' + str(offset)

    def target_func(self, start, end):
        for offset in range(start, end + 1, 1000):
            query = self.books_query(offset)
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            books = cursor.fetchall()

            # Doing something with this data.

start = 0
obj = A()
for i in xrange(12):
    end = start + 1000
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name='process_' + str(end), target=obj.target_func, args=(start, end))
    p.start()
    start = end + 1
```

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: Multiprocessing but with single connection. Write query to cursor but where your minimal delay (executing time).

Comment: Sorry. Couldn't get you. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Set a query if old is success/finished/raised-error . You can't execute any query if cursor is busy.  Need create a new connection  for every thread block's !

Comment: While "if got_query_answer" , "if cursor_on_prepare_data", "if query_is_done","if query_is_failed" etc.